# Recursive copy to relative destination paths

Tags: bash, shell

I was thinking something like what I'm trying to accomplish could be done with built in shell tools w/o the need for a more complicated script.

I'd like to find all the files in a path and copy them to a destination basepath retaining the relative paths they were found in.

Example:

Say I ran:

```
[~:] find /path/src  \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.gif" \)
```

and that returned:

```
/path/src/a.jpg
/path/src/dir1/b.jpg
/path/src/dir2/dir3/c.gif
```

I'd like them to all end up in:

```
/path/dest/a.jpg
/path/dest/dir1/b.jpg
/path/dest/dir2/dir3/c.gif
```

I tried an `-exec cp {} /path/dest \;` flag to `find` but that just dumped everything in /path/dest.  E.g:

```
/path/dest/a.jpg
/path/dest/b.jpg
/path/dest/c.gif
```

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) for this, e.g.

```
$ rsync -avm /path/src/ /path/dest/ --include \*/ --include \*.jpg --include \*.gif --exclude \*
```

Just to clarify the above:

```
-avm             # recursive, copy attributes etc, verbose, skip empty directories
/path/src/       # source
/path/dest/      # destination (NB: trailing / is important)
--include \*/    # include all directories
--include \*.jpg # include files ending .jpg
--include \*.gif # include files ending .gif
--exclude \*     # exclude all other files
```

Comment: Does find has abilities to handle this situation?

Comment: You *might* be able to do it with `find` but it seems like it would be more work and more error-prone, so `rsync` is probably a much better tool for this particular job.

Comment: @PaulR it doesn't work at all - I just created an xcode project, placed this script into its directory and run: `rsync -av . result/ --include \*.strings --exclude \*`. Zero files!

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov: you left out the `--include \*/`. Also you're making (possibly incorrect) assumptions about current working directory when runnign a script under Xcode.

Comment: @PaulR if I add this then it includes all subfolders but makes them empty. There should be `--prune-empty-dirs` but you didn't mention it. So it is not an answer

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov: thank you for the helpful comment - I’ve edited the answer to include `-m` now.

Answer (score 9):

Actually it also works with cp, what you want is the --parents flag.

```
cp --parents `find /path/src  \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.gif" \)` /path/target
```

In theory `-P` is synonyms with `--parents`, but that never worked for me.

Comment: Your answer is correct:  `--parents` is the right answer. However, `-P` is wrong (its meaning is: `never follow symbolic links in SOURCE` and is synonym for `--no-dereference`

Comment: Note: `--parents` is a GNU extension to POSIX.

Comment: @CiroSantilli Good point. But then again how many systems do you know **that are actively used** don't build on top of GNU or GNU conventions? [Even the BSD cp implementation is GNU](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cp&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=Red+Hat+Linux%2Fi386+9&format=html).

Comment: @rioki, i know of such system; **OS X**